# Connecting EC2 to RDS via php

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am having a problem with connecting to my RDS via the PHP mySQLi connect function. I have established the connection through mySQL Workbench and through a remote connection in the UBUNTU terminal, but cannot connect through the php code within my index file which is on the EC2 Instance. I have triple checked everything and have added the extension=mysqli.so within the php.ini file nothing has worked so far. Is there a security group I am missing that needs to be added?

PHP code for connection:

```
mysql_connect("Address", "Username", "Password", TRUE) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("DB_NAME") or die("No database by that name");
```

Also tried:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('Address', 'Username', 'Password', 'DB_NAME', 'PORT');

if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) { echo "Good<br />\n"; } else { echo "Bad.<br />\n"; }
```

and I receive neither good nor bad as a return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the rds security group, whether port number 3306 is allowed to ec2 instance ip address. 
Or try to login to rds instance from ec2 instance terminal,check whether connection is establishing or not.

Comment: Okay, I've logged in successfully from the EC2 terminal, and am on port 3306 with the IP adress of the EC2, however am not getting connection through the index.php webpage...

Comment: You have to check the security group that was used by rds instance. in that security group check the rules for port no 3306

Comment: Do you have some documentation that may be able to show me the exact security groups I need to add and where? I can connect via the terminal by running the script mysql -h DB_location -u USERNAME -p

Comment: Please go through below link ,you will get more idea about security  groups .http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html